# Python plot: Unequal positioning of axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I generated the following plot using `plt.plot(x,y)`

[image: This is the plot]

As you can see, the position of the label 1/epsilon is different from the positioning of the other labels.

How can this issue be fixed?

This is the array with the labels:

```
x = [s.strip('\(\)') for s in ['$\epsilon^2$', '$\epsilon^1$', '$1/\epsilon$','$1/\epsilon^2$',
                               '$1/\epsilon^3$']]
```

I have not found a solution so far.
Could I show the labels using `\frac{}{}`?

Comment: What exactly are we supposed to be looking at?

Comment: @jared the `1/epsilon` label has a different vertical position than the others. It looks to be positioned a bit higher.

Comment: @Sylvia `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), va="bottom", y=-0.05)` seems to be a bit better looking.